# How to show that $\exp(X)$ has a lognormal pdf if $X$ has a normal pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian

Given: $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$

Show that $\exp(X)$ has a lognormal distribution.

Attempt:
\begin{align}
    \text{Let } Y = e^X \ \ \text{and} \ \ Y \sim p_Y(y) \\
    P(Y \leq t) = \int_{-\infty}^{t} f_Y(y)dy \\
    P(Y \leq t) = P(e^X \leq t) = P(X \leq ln(t)) \\
    P(X \leq ln(t)) = \int_{-\infty}^{ln(t)} \mathcal{N_X(\mu, \sigma^2)}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{ln(t)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{t} f_Y(y)dy
\end{align}

I am stuck at this point. I know what the final form looks like, but I can't figure out how to get there. I do not believe that I need to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{ln(t)} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx$?

Any hints?

Comment: Perhaps this is ignorant on my part, but what is there to show? Isn't that the definition of a lognormal distribution?

Comment: @zugzug Is what the definition of a lognormal distribution? I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious

Comment: The definition from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution#Definitions

Comment: Are you referring to the $\frac{1}{x\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}exp(-\frac{(ln(x)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})$? If so, I am not sure how my expression in the OP is supposed to simplify to that

Comment: In your last step, use the substituion $x= \ln u$. After you rewrite in terms of $u$, you can change $u$ back to $x$ if it looks nicer.

Comment: Ahh I completely forgot about the u-sub. I usually only tihnk about doing it when I'm really intending on performing the actual integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've reached

$$ P(Y \leq t) = \int^{\log t}_{-\infty} f_X(x) dx$$

and as you've said, you don't need to evaluate that integral to get $f_Y(t),$ you just need to differentiate both sides with respect to $t.$ By the fundamental theorem of calculus (and the chain rule), you get $$ f_Y(t) = f_X(\log t) \cdot \frac{1}{t}$$ which is the density function you are looking for.

More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables such that $Y= g(X)$ for some monotonically increasing function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ then we have 
$$f_Y(y) = f_X( g^{-1}(y) ) \cdot \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y).$$

This is proved by following essentially the same steps that you did above.

Comment: Isn't $t$ technically a constant?

Comment: @Iamanon $t$ is the variable of the cumulative density function $F_Y(t) = P(Y \leq t)$

Comment: Right. Hmm, I actually was envisioning $t$ to be a constant in my derivation, which would make differentiation with respect to it nonsensical.

Comment: What is the significance of the inverse $g(y)$ here?

Comment: @Iamanon It's how you can express $x$ in terms of $y.$ You can imagine the formula as $f_Y(y) = f_X(x) \cdot \frac{dx}{dy}$ and just remember that since you required a function of $y$ you need to express the terms involving $x$ on the right hand side with terms involving $y$ instead.